# Instagram promotion

Tags: instagram

I've tried different promotional bots before, but the problem is the same for all - Instagram blocks activity and nothing works. 
Do you know any tool that works well? I really need it in order to find new customers for my offer, but it's really annoying to lose time and money.
Or I should forget about that idea?

Answer (score 0):

Do not even try to use automation bots, because they break Instagram rules. I used a couple of them and result is all the same - the account gets banned.

Now I am testing a new tool called Ingramer, they have a different algorithm and it seem to be a good solution.